# Convert Excel 4.0 macro to VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba

Is there a tool to convert Excel 4.0 macros to VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out: [Mr. Excel](http://www.mrexcel.com/archive/VBA/18020.html)

Basically says no tool to convert, but you should be able to use the xlm.

I bet if you post the macro it would be converted.

Answer (score -1):

When you create a macro in Excel in the background VBA code is written. What else you want to do. You can even edit and modify the VBA code.

Comment: How can you access that macro code? Can you expand your answer a little maybe?

Comment: The key is 'Excel 4.0', a much older version and mechanism.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/privileges/comment).